# Need guidance on mongo aggregate lookup to count subnodes in all child nodes for each node

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

To better understand my problem, I've created a fake scenario of counting leaves in forests at all levels.

I need to provide total counts of leaves for all forests, for each forest, for each tree, and for each branch.  Thus, I need to output a tree structure that has all this info along with the IDs of each element so they can be identified.

Input data comes from 2 collections - forests and leaves.  I need to join the forests and leaves on branch_id, and output leaf counts and inject these counts into a structure equivalent to the forests collection (as a query result - not stored in the database).  Memory usage is a concern.  I was thinking I could do a join and read all these ids into memory, but there may be up to 100 forests.  Each forest likely has up to 10 trees, each tree has about 25 branches, each branch has up to 15 leaves.

```
Forests collection
[
    {
        forest_id: 'forestA',
        trees: [
            {
                tree_id: 'treeA',
                branches: [
                    {
                         branch_id: 'branchA',
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

Leaves collection
[
    {
        leaf_id: 'leafA',
        branch_id: 'branchA'
    }
]
```

This is the desired output:

```
{
    leaf_count: 9999999999,
    forests: [
       {
            leaf_count: 8888888,
            forest_id: 'forestA',
            trees: [
                {
                    leaf_count: 77777,
                    tree_id: 'treeA',
                    branches: [
                        {
                            leaf_count: 6666,
                            branch_id
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The aggregate pipeline I'm working on has all the desired output (built up to this point) in it, without any of the counts.  I'm thinking I need  to use facets here, and I'm worried about performance and I'm looking for what I should learn about to tackle this properly.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the test data from [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bN_jusvsXTv) MongoPlaygroud link.

**NOTE**: You can skip all `$sort` stages in the above link for the sake of performance.

Query to get count of leaves:

```js
db.Forests.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$trees" },
    { $unwind: "$trees.branches" },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Leaves",
            localField: "trees.branches.branch_id",
            foreignField: "branch_id",
            as: "trees.branches.leaves"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "trees.branches.leaf_count": { $size: "$trees.branches.leaves" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { "trees.branches.leaves": 0 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                forest_id: "$forest_id",
                tree_id: "$trees.tree_id"
            },
            leaf_count: { $sum: "$trees.branches.leaf_count" },
            branches: { $push: "$trees.branches" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.forest_id",
            leaf_count: { $sum: "$leaf_count" },
            trees: {
                $push: {
                    leaf_count: { $sum: "$leaf_count" },
                    tree_id: "$_id.tree_id",
                    branches: "$branches"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            leaf_count: { $sum: "$leaf_count" },
            forests: {
                $push: {
                    leaf_count: { $sum: "$leaf_count" },
                    forest_id: "$_id",
                    trees: "$trees"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { _id: 0 }
    }
])
```

Output:

```js
{
    "leaf_count" : 4,
    "forests" : [
        {
            "leaf_count" : 3,
            "forest_id" : "forestA",
            "trees" : [
                {
                    "leaf_count" : 2,
                    "tree_id" : "treeA",
                    "branches" : [
                        {
                            "branch_id" : "branchA",
                            "leaf_count" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "branch_id" : "branchA1",
                            "leaf_count" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "branch_id" : "branchA2",
                            "leaf_count" : 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "leaf_count" : 1,
                    "tree_id" : "treeB",
                    "branches" : [
                        {
                            "branch_id" : "branchB",
                            "leaf_count" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "leaf_count" : 1,
            "forest_id" : "forestB",
            "trees" : [
                {
                    "leaf_count" : 1,
                    "tree_id" : "treeC",
                    "branches" : [
                        {
                            "branch_id" : "branchC",
                            "leaf_count" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "leaf_count" : 0,
                    "tree_id" : "treeD",
                    "branches" : [
                        {
                            "branch_id" : "branchD",
                            "leaf_count" : 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "leaf_count" : 0,
            "forest_id" : "forestC",
            "trees" : [
                {
                    "leaf_count" : 0,
                    "tree_id" : "treeE",
                    "branches" : [
                        {
                            "branch_id" : "branchE",
                            "leaf_count" : 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: WOW!  There is so much loaded in your answer for me to understand and digest! Thank you so much! I will take the rest of the evening to digest this!

Comment: Well, I just tried to buy you a coffee, but the site doesn't work...  :-(

Comment: You.are.awesome.

Comment: Thanks! Check out these 2 courses by MongoDB: https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M001/about & https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M121/about Its free and will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I will check those out when I get a chance!  May I ask - what if the input was slightly different?  Instead of receiving an array of forests, you have an object like this: {"forests": [usual array], "reference": {some object}}?  I ask because the input I described is very close to what I have in the middle of my pipeline and I don't know how to store "reference" for later so I can get it back...

Comment: The aggregation framework course for my case looks like an absolute gem, thank you again!

Comment: Hoping to get your help one last time on this follow-up question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66847845/mongodb-aggregation-setting-the-contents-of-array-as-input-while-storing-sibl

Comment: That is the main disadvantage of using `$group`. You have to explicitly carry forward every non participating fields using either `$first` or `$last` like this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#example