# mongodb aggregation - setting the contents of array as input, while storing sibling keys

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm in the middle of an aggregation pipeline when I have the following data passed from the previous step as input to a "count all leaves in all branches/trees/forests" as indicated in this question:  [Need guidance on mongo aggregate lookup to count subnodes in all child nodes for each node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66831784/need-guidance-on-mongo-aggregate-lookup-to-count-subnodes-in-all-child-nodes-for/66832288?noredirect=1#comment118149374_66832288)

```
{
    forest_ranger: "bob",
    some_other_data: {},
    forests: [
      {
        forest_id: 'forestA',
        trees: [
          {
            tree_id: 'treeA',
            branches: [
              {
                 branch_id: 'branchA',
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
}
```

I have that all working properly, but only if I'm reading directly from a collection.

My question is - how can I

```
a)  save forest_ranger and some_other_data "for later"
b)  and start the next stage by mapping forests as the array of
    documents that are input to the "count all leaves"?
```

Note - I tried to get just (b) working for starters, but I can't seem to treat "forests" as an array so that the solution in the link above can do its magic.

Then- when that phase is done, extract what was stored in (a) to get the original format back with all the counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the main disadvantage of using `$group`. You have to explicitly carry forward every non participating fields using either [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#example) or [$last](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#example) like this:

Get the test data with those additional fields from [this new](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hFf9_8AAFP-) MongoPlayground link.

Check the updated query taken from the link:

```js
db.Forests.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$forests" },
    { $unwind: "$forests.trees" },
    { $unwind: "$forests.trees.branches" },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Leaves",
            localField: "forests.trees.branches.branch_id",
            foreignField: "branch_id",
            as: "forests.trees.branches.leaves"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "forests.trees.branches.leaf_count": { $size: "$forests.trees.branches.leaves" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { "forests.trees.branches.leaves": 0 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                forest_id: "$forests.forest_id",
                tree_id: "$forests.trees.tree_id"
            },
            forest_ranger: { $first: "$forest_ranger" },
            some_other_data: { $first: "$some_other_data" },
            leaf_count: { $sum: "$forests.trees.branches.leaf_count" },
            branches: { $push: "$forests.trees.branches" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.forest_id",
            forest_ranger: { $first: "$forest_ranger" },
            some_other_data: { $first: "$some_other_data" },
            leaf_count: { $sum: "$leaf_count" },
            trees: {
                $push: {
                    leaf_count: { $sum: "$leaf_count" },
                    tree_id: "$_id.tree_id",
                    branches: "$branches"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            forest_ranger: { $first: "$forest_ranger" },
            some_other_data: { $first: "$some_other_data" },
            leaf_count: { $sum: "$leaf_count" },
            forests: {
                $push: {
                    leaf_count: { $sum: "$leaf_count" },
                    forest_id: "$_id",
                    trees: "$trees"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { _id: 0 }
    }
])
```

Output:

```js
{
    "forest_ranger" : "bob",
    "some_other_data" : {
        "data" : "Dummy data"
    },
    "leaf_count" : 4,
    "forests" : [
        {
            "leaf_count" : 3,
            "forest_id" : "forestA",
            "trees" : [
                {
                    "leaf_count" : 1,
                    "tree_id" : "treeB",
                    "branches" : [
                        {
                            "branch_id" : "branchB",
                            "leaf_count" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "leaf_count" : 2,
                    "tree_id" : "treeA",
                    "branches" : [
                        {
                            "branch_id" : "branchA",
                            "leaf_count" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "branch_id" : "branchA1",
                            "leaf_count" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "branch_id" : "branchA2",
                            "leaf_count" : 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "leaf_count" : 1,
            "forest_id" : "forestB",
            "trees" : [
                {
                    "leaf_count" : 0,
                    "tree_id" : "treeD",
                    "branches" : [
                        {
                            "branch_id" : "branchD",
                            "leaf_count" : 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "leaf_count" : 1,
                    "tree_id" : "treeC",
                    "branches" : [
                        {
                            "branch_id" : "branchC",
                            "leaf_count" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "leaf_count" : 0,
            "forest_id" : "forestC",
            "trees" : [
                {
                    "leaf_count" : 0,
                    "tree_id" : "treeE",
                    "branches" : [
                        {
                            "branch_id" : "branchE",
                            "leaf_count" : 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks again so much! I did try unwinding forests first like this- works in the playground, but not in code. In my code, the result I get back from unwinding forests combines the forest id and I completely lose the 2nd forest id. Now that I know I was on the right track, I'll probably be able to dig deeper and see why this is happening. I'm pretty sure the input is exactly the same in both playground and code, so it's really confusing..